# How to merge two DataTables like this?

Tags: c#, system.data.datatable

I have two datatables

```
dtTable1:
Name    Id  Contact
Gems    A1  8888880000
George  A2  0000008888

dtTable2:
Col1    Col2    Col3
XXX1    YYY1    ZZZ1
XXX2    YYY2    ZZZ2
XXX3    YYY3    ZZZ3
XXX4    YYY4    ZZZ4
```

My required DataTable is:

```
Name    Id  Contact         Col1    Col2    Col3
Gems    A1  8888880000  XXX1    YYY1    ZZZ1
George  A2  0000008888  XXX2    YYY2    ZZZ2
null    null   null     XXX3    YYY3    ZZZ3
null    null   null     XXX4    YYY4    ZZZ4
```

How can I do it with C#

Comment: There's not a framework function to accomplish this, so you'll need to come up with a process.  e.g. Loop through rows and add to a new datatable.

Comment: Are you talking about `System.Data.DataTable`? Your “required Datatable” is not a `System.Data.DataTable`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13156626/join-2-datatables-with-many-columns

Comment: All the three Tables are System.Data.DataTable. first two tables do not have any common column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go. Might not be pretty but does the job.
No matter which DataTable has more row it will add them.

```
private static DataTable MergeTables(DataTable dt1, DataTable dt2)
{
    DataTable merged = new DataTable();

    //copy column struct from dt1
    merged = dt1.Clone();

    //create columns from dt2
    foreach (DataColumn col in dt2.Columns)
    {
        merged.Columns.Add(col.ColumnName);
    }

    int rows;

    if (dt1.Rows.Count > dt2.Rows.Count)
    {
        rows = dt1.Rows.Count;
    }
    else
    {
        rows = dt2.Rows.Count;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        DataRow row = merged.NewRow();

        if ( i < dt1.Rows.Count)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < dt1.Columns.Count; c++)
            {
                row[c] = dt1.Rows[i][c];
            }
        }

        if (i < dt2.Rows.Count)
        {
            for (int c2 = dt1.Columns.Count; c2 < dt2.Columns.Count + dt1.Columns.Count; c2++)
            {
                row[c2] = dt2.Rows[i][c2-dt1.Columns.Count];
            }
        }
        merged.Rows.Add(row);
    }
    return merged;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DataTable mergeDataTables(DataTable dt1, DataTable dt2)
{
    if(dt1.Rows.Count != dt2.Rows.Count ) throw new Exception();

    var dtResult = new DataTable();

    //add new columns
    foreach (DataColumn col in dt1.Columns)
        dtResult.Columns.Add(col.ColumnName, col.DataType);

    foreach (DataColumn col in dt2.Columns)
        dtResult.Columns.Add(col.ColumnName, col.DataType);

    //fill data
    for (int i = 0; i < dt1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        dtResult.Rows.Add(dt1.Rows[i].ItemArray.Concat(dt2.Rows[i].ItemArray).ToArray());
    }

    return dtResult;
}
```

Comment: With this solution, I can Create the Column headers only. But I have different number of rows in the DataTables. if(dt1.Rows.Count != dt2.Rows.Count ) throw new Exception(); it throws exception at the start.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed solution of lomed.

May be this not perfect solution. But it works for the similar scenario as required in the question:

```
DataTable MergeDataTables(DataTable dt1, DataTable dt2)
    {
        var dtResult = new DataTable();

        foreach (DataColumn col in dt1.Columns)
            dtResult.Columns.Add(col.ColumnName, col.DataType);

        foreach (DataColumn col in dt2.Columns)
            dtResult.Columns.Add(col.ColumnName, col.DataType);

        //cond: to check which if datatable1 is bigger
        if (dt1.Rows.Count > dt2.Rows.Count)
        {               
            for (int i = 0; i < dt1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                if (i < dt2.Rows.Count)
                    dtResult.Rows.Add(dt1.Rows[i].ItemArray.Concat(dt2.Rows[i].ItemArray).ToArray());
                else
                {
                    DataRow dr = dtResult.NewRow();
                    foreach (DataColumn col in dt1.Columns)                       
                        dr[col.ColumnName] = dt1.Rows[i][col.ColumnName];
                    dtResult.Rows.Add(dr);
                }                

            }
        }
        //if rows equal or datatable2 is bigger
        else
        {                
            for (int i = 0; i < dt2.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                if (i < dt1.Rows.Count)
                    dtResult.Rows.Add(dt1.Rows[i].ItemArray.Concat(dt2.Rows[i].ItemArray).ToArray());
                else
                {
                    DataRow dr = dtResult.NewRow();
                    foreach (DataColumn col in dt2.Columns)                                                  
                        dr[col.ColumnName] = dt2.Rows[i][col.ColumnName];
                    dtResult.Rows.Add(dr);
                }
            }                
        }

       return dtResult;
    }
```