# Outer Joining two Data Tables on multiple criteria

Tags: c#, .net, linq, join

I'm trying to join two DataTables using Linq based on multiple criteria. I was able to get a merge working using this post: [Combining two tables into one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13169314/combining-two-tables-into-one/13169370#13169370). However, that example only joins on one primary key and I need to be able to specify multiple criteria.

DataTable1(table1 in code)

```
+-----------------------------------------------+
| CLIENT,USER_NAME,LAST_LOGIN_DT_TM,BIRTH_DT_TM |
+-----------------------------------------------+
| CLIENT1, USER1, 30-2014, 5-5-1980             |
| CLIENT1, USER2, 12-21-2014, 5-2-1990          |
| CLIENT2, USER3, 11-30-2014, 5-1-1950          |
| CLIENT2, USER4, 12-15-2014, 1-1-1900          |
+-----------------------------------------------+
```

DataTable 2(table2 in code)

```
+-------------------------------+
| CLIENT,USER_NAME,TOTAL_ORDERS |
+-------------------------------+
| CLIENT1, USER1, 1500          |
| CLIENT2, USER2, 2500          |
+-------------------------------+
```

I want the output to look like this:

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| CLIENT,USER_NAME,LAST_LOGIN_DT_TM,BIRTH_DT_TM, TOTAL_ORDERS |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| CLIENT1, USER1, 1-30-2014, 5-5-1980, 1500                   |
| CLIENT1, USER2, 12-21-2014, 5-2-1990,                       |
| CLIENT2, USER2, 11-30-2014, 5-1-1950, 2500                  |
| CLIENT2, USER1, 12-15-2014, 1-1-1900,                       |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
DataTable targetTable = table1.Clone();

var dt2Columns = table2.Columns
                       .OfType<DataColumn>()
                       .Select(dc => new DataColumn(dc.ColumnName, dc.DataType, dc.Expression, dc.ColumnMapping));
var dt2FinalColumns = from dc in dt2Columns.AsEnumerable()
                      where targetTable.Columns.Contains(dc.ColumnName) == false
                      select dc;
                      targetTable.Columns.AddRange(dt2FinalColumns.ToArray());

//  This only matches on USER_NAME now, how do I add in CLIENT?
var rowData = from row1 in table1.AsEnumerable()
              join row2 in table2.AsEnumerable()
              on row1.Field<string>("USER_NAME") equals row2.Field<string>("USER_NAME")
              select row1; 
// This gives me the matched rows in rowData, but I'm not sure how to join it with original table1
```

Answer (score 4):

To join on multiple columns you have to use anonymous types:

```
from row1 in table1.AsEnumerable()
join row2 in table2.AsEnumerable() on
  new { userName = row1.Field<string>("USER_NAME"), client = row1.Field<string>("CLIENT") }
equals
  new { userName = row2.Field<string>("USER_NAME"), client = row2.Field<string>("CLIENT") }
select new {
    userName = row1.Field<string>("USER_NAME"),
    client = row1.Field<string>("CLIENT"),
    totalOrders = row2.Field<int>("TOTAL_ORDERS"),
    (...)
}
```

Comment: This takes care of the matching and puts the two matched rows into rowData. What's the best way after that to get to my desired output of the outer join?

Comment: You can project to a different anonymous type. Updated my answer.

Comment: what if I don't know all of the columns in each DataTable until run-time? In my real world scenario, table1 has about 55 columns and table2 has 25 or so. All I know is that each table has both "CLIENT" and "USER_NAME" columns.

Comment: Yes,  i made a mistake , my code would not compile. But, even, your code does not compile, you are missing the Quotes for "Client" :)

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek sorry didn't tag you in my previous comment. Any ideas if I don't know the columns in each DataTable until run-time? I would like to avoid having to write out 50+ columns in my code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

FielYou need to Join using Anonymous Type by using new {Field1, Field2}

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> rowData = from row1 in table1.AsEnumerable()
          join row2 in table2.AsEnumerable()
          on new { col1 = row1.Field<string>("USER_NAME"),  col2 = row1.Field<string>("SecondField") }  equals {col1 = row2.Field<string>("USER_NAME") , col2 = row2.Field<string>("SecondField") }
          select row1;
```

Comment: Won't compile. That's not a correct anonymous type declaration, because compiler will not be able to infer property names for you.