# LINQ CustomDataRowEqualityComparer

Tags: c#, linq

i am using a `CustomDataRowEqualityComparer()` to compare 2 datatables with different number of columns but they share some columns:

```
var result= maindatatable.AsEnumerable().Except(dt.AsEnumerable(), new CustomDataRowEqualityComparer()).CopyToDataTable();
```

how can i make the result datatable contain only the columns in `dt`?, in the aboVe contex the

result datatable have the columns of the `maindatatable`

Here is my comparer class

```
public class CustomDataRowEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<DataRow>
    {
        public bool Equals(DataRow x, DataRow y)
        {
            return ((int)x["id"] == (int)y["id"]);
        }

        public int GetHashCode(DataRow obj)
        {
            return ((int)obj["id"]);
        }

    }
```

it returns all rows in `maindatatable` that doesnt exist in `dt`

Comment: Use `DataTable.Merge`. Have a look at my custom implementation which allows to union tables on a named column(like your `id`): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12278978/combining-n-datatables-into-a-single-datatable/12284003#12284003 I guess that it's what you want here too.

Comment: @TimSchmelter not exactly, all rows in dt exist in main datatable, in the result datatable i want to select rows from maindatatable that doesnt exist in dt, the code i attached is working fine but i am not sure how to select te columns i want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you don't know how to return the main-table with all rows that are **not** in `dt` but with columns of `dt`.

In general, you cannot select rows from `maintable` with columns from another `DataTable`. Therefore you have to fill a new instance of `dt`(use `dt.Clone()` to create all columns) with these rows.

So for example(assuming that the columns of table `dt` exist also in `maintable` but not vice-versa):

```
var result = maindatatable.AsEnumerable()
    .Except(dt.AsEnumerable(), new CustomDataRowEqualityComparer());
var dt2 = dt.Clone();
foreach(DataRow mainRow in result)
{
    var newRow = dt2.Rows.Add();
    foreach (DataColumn col in dt2.Columns)
        newRow[col] = mainRow[col.ColumnName];
}
```