# How to merge two datatables, which having different schema?

Tags: c#, sql, datatable, dataset

I have two **Datatables** shown in below

Table 1

```
-------------------------
  ID  |   Name 
--------------------------
 1    |  JOHN
 2    |  GEORGE
 3    |  RAGU
--------------------------
```

Table 2

```
  ----------
   ID | AGE
  ----------
    1 | 23
    2 | 23
    3 | 22
  ----------
```

I just want the result as like this..

Result

```
-------------------------
  ID  |   Name    | AGE
--------------------------
 1    |  JOHN     | 23
 2    |  GEORGE   | 23
 3    |  RAGU     | 22
--------------------------
```

Thanks..

Comment: Where did you get stuck ?

Comment: The data in a table has no inherent sequence. How do you know, that `23` is the "first" age and `22` is the "third"?

Comment: when using datatable merge concept i got the result like 6 rows, first 3 rows contains only ID and Name , the next 3 rows contains only age..

Comment: If you `SELECT AGE FROM AGETABLE` without any `ORDER BY`, you *might* get the ages in that sequence, but it is not guaranteed you will. Without `ORDER BY` the server is free to give you data in any order it likes.

Comment: @Corak Now i put ID for AGE Table..

Comment: @ragu: set relationship between both tables ids in your datatabase

Comment: possible duplicate of [Combining n DataTables into a Single DataTable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12278978/combining-n-datatables-into-a-single-datatable)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can check this out:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Program p = new Program();
    DataTable dt1= p.Get1();
    DataTable dt2 = p.Get2();          
    DataTable dt3 = p.Get3(dt1, dt2);
}
public DataTable Get1()
{
    DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
    dt1.Columns.Add("ID");
    dt1.Columns.Add("Name");
    dt1.Rows.Add("1", "JOHN");
    dt1.Rows.Add("2", "GEORGE");
    dt1.Rows.Add("3", "RAGU");        
    return dt1;
}

public DataTable Get2()
{
    DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
    dt2.Columns.Add("AGE");         
    dt2.Rows.Add("23");
    dt2.Rows.Add("23");
    dt2.Rows.Add("22");
    return dt2;
}

public DataTable Get3(DataTable dt1,DataTable dt2)
{
    dt1.Columns.Add("Age");
    for (int i = 0; i < dt1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        dt1.Rows[i]["Age"] = dt2.Rows[i]["Age"];
    }
    return dt1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you heard about [INNER JOIN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms190014.aspx)?

Basically, what you want to do is:

```
SELECT Persons.ID, Persons.Name, Ages.Age 
FROM Persons INNER JOIN Ages ON Persons.ID = Ages.ID
```

Now you can insert that into another table if you want.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that this is what you might be looking for

```
INSERT INTO Result (ID, Name, Age)
SELECT T1.ID, T1.Name, T2.Age
FROM
    Table1 AS T1
INNER JOIN
    Table2 AS T2
ON 
    T1.ID = T2.ID
ORDER BY
    T1.ID
```