# merge two datatable arrays C#

Tags: c#, join, merge

i have two datatable arrays

```
  DataTable[] DTrightSplitH2;
  DataTable[] DTleftSplitH2;
```

what i try to do is to take each datatable in DTright and compare to DTleft in "key" columns
it they are the same, merge the row

i know i should use DataTable.Merge with bool set to false and adding missing schema but i can't make it work like i want

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
DTrightSplitH2.Union(DTleftSplitH2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds as if you could use my [`MergeAll`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12284003/284240) method (usage below).

```
public static DataTable MergeAll(this IList<DataTable> tables, String primaryKeyColumn)
{
    if (!tables.Any())
        throw new ArgumentException("Tables must not be empty", "tables");
    if(primaryKeyColumn != null)
        foreach(DataTable t in tables)
            if(!t.Columns.Contains(primaryKeyColumn))
                throw new ArgumentException("All tables must have the specified primarykey column " + primaryKeyColumn, "primaryKeyColumn");

    if(tables.Count == 1)
        return tables[0];

    DataTable table = new DataTable("TblUnion");
    table.BeginLoadData(); // Turns off notifications, index maintenance, and constraints while loading data
    foreach (DataTable t in tables)
    {
        foreach (DataColumn col in t.Columns) 
            col.ReadOnly = false; // required e.g. if you use a DataSet with Foreign-Key Constraints
        table.Merge(t); // same as table.Merge(t, false, MissingSchemaAction.Add);
    }
    table.EndLoadData();

    if (primaryKeyColumn != null)
    {
        // since we might have no real primary keys defined, the rows now might have repeating fields
        // so now we're going to "join" these rows ...
        var pkGroups = table.AsEnumerable()
            .GroupBy(r => r[primaryKeyColumn]);
        var dupGroups = pkGroups.Where(g => g.Count() > 1);
        foreach (var grpDup in dupGroups)
        { 
            // use first row and modify it
            DataRow firstRow = grpDup.First();
            foreach (DataColumn c in table.Columns)
            {
                if (firstRow.IsNull(c))
                {
                    DataRow firstNotNullRow = grpDup.Skip(1).FirstOrDefault(r => !r.IsNull(c));
                    if (firstNotNullRow != null)
                        firstRow[c] = firstNotNullRow[c];
                }
            }
            // remove all but first row
            var rowsToRemove = grpDup.Skip(1);
            foreach(DataRow rowToRemove in rowsToRemove)
                table.Rows.Remove(rowToRemove);
        }
    }

    return table;
}
```

Usage:

```
var tables = DTrightSplitH2.Concat(DTleftSplitH2).ToArray();
DataTable TblUnion = tables.MergeAll("key");
```

Comment: there is a key in each table

Comment: Then you should show an example of the structure of some tables and a desired result.