# How to get DataTable From DataSet?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, datatable

I have a `DataSet ds` which contains 10 DataTables, each have one column only. How to make a `DataTable` that contains all the columns from `DataSet ds`?

---

```
public static DataSet ReadXmlUsingBufferedStream(string pathOfXMLFile) 
{ 
   DataSet ds = new DataSet(); 
   ds.EnforceConstraints = false; 
   if (File.Exists(pathOfXMLFile)) 
   { 
      using (FileStream filestream = File.OpenRead(pathOfXMLFile)) 
      { 
         BufferedStream buffered = new BufferedStream(filestream);
         ds.ReadXml(buffered); 
      } 
   } 
   ds.EnforceConstraints = true; 
   return ds; 
}
```

Comment: How are you filling `DataSet`? show us that code.

Comment: hi @pranay is you mean you want new data table which will have 10 columns each from your 10 seprate data tables ? and does this all data tables have same numbers of rows?

Comment: @PushkarPhule hi, yes.

Comment: @Bharadwaj public static DataSet ReadXmlUsingBufferedStream(string pathOfXMLFile)
       {
           DataSet ds = new DataSet();
           ds.EnforceConstraints = false;

               if (File.Exists(pathOfXMLFile))
               {
                   using (FileStream filestream = File.OpenRead(pathOfXMLFile))
                   {
                       BufferedStream buffered = new BufferedStream(filestream);
                       ds.ReadXml(buffered);
                   }
               }

           ds.EnforceConstraints = true;
           return ds;
       }

Comment: does this all data tables have same numbers of rows?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12278978/combining-n-datatables-into-a-single-datatable

is this solving your problem  ? @pranay

Comment: @PushkarPhule - yes it has same no. of rows

Comment: @PranayDeep please don't put additional code into comments - edit your question instead (the comment code is unreadable)

Comment: @PushkarPhule - Thanks for the link, but it is DataTable Class which i am talking about in c# .net

Comment: @pranay use this 

dtAll = dtOne.Copy();
dtAll.Merge(dtTwo);

Comment: your problem is that you have no key to associate the values if you only have one column - so if you want to do it by index it should be as easy as two for-loops

Comment: Check your `xml` structure, it may be because of the structure it is creating new tables. Try using `DataTable.ReadXml()` to read it to the `DataTable` instead of `DataSet`.

Comment: Do you just need the scema of each table or just name or everithing related to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I just have marged all `datatabes` available in `dataset`. If you set any condition that, you will add certain columns of certain table, than this should be enhanced.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Building a dataset having 10 different datatable which contains 1 column each
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();            
            for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Columns.Add("dt" + i + "_column1", typeof(string));
                dt.AcceptChanges();
                ds.Tables.Add(dt);

            }
            ds.AcceptChanges();

            //Here finally building a datatable which consists all columns of each and every tables in dataset
            DataTable dtFinal = new DataTable();
            foreach (DataTable tmp in ds.Tables)
            {
                dtFinal.Merge(tmp);
            }
        }
    }
}
```