# Copy two dataTables to another table in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have two dataTables which I want to union to make one final dataTable.
Both are results of different functions.

I tried this :

```
dtfinal = dt1.Copy()
dtfinal = dt2.Copy()
```

But here dt2 data is replaced by dt1. What should be used to get union of both into the final dt.

Comment: Can I just double check what you mean by "union"? Are you asking in the SQL UNION sense? The UNION ALL sense? Or is "union" a typo and you mean a join?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`DataTable.Merge`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.merge?view=net-6.0):

```
Dim allTables() As DataTable = {dt1, dt2}
Dim dtfinal = new DataTable("dtfinal")
dtfinal.BeginLoadData() ' Turns off notifications, index maintenance, and constraints while loading data
For Each t As DataTable in allTables
    dtfinal.Merge(t) ' same as table.Merge(t, false, MissingSchemaAction.Add)
Next
dtfinal.EndLoadData()
```

If you don't have primary keys specified you could end up with repeating rows where you actually want to merge them. Then either specify the PKs or use this method i have provided here(needs conversion from C#):

[Combining n DataTables into a Single DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12278978/combining-n-datatables-into-a-single-datatable)